# Missing Relative Transform in AddPhysicsHandleComponent

Tags: physics, game-physics, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to rebuild the tutorial "Pick Up Physics Object Tutorial" and I need to use "Relative Transform" in "AddPhysicsHandleComponent" but it is not there. 
On this site https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/AddComponent/Physics/AddPhysicsHandleComponent/index.html the AddPhysicsHandleComponent is shown exactly the way I need it but in Unreal Engine itself it appears without the "Relative Transform". 
Does someone know what I can use instead of the AddPhysicsHandleComponent? Or is there a way to make it let me use "Relative Transform"?

Here is the link to the tutorial: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Pick_Up_Physics_Object_Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just call "Set Target Location and Rotation" on your physics handle.[image]